# SQLite - Counting referenced rows in one table using a different, related self-referencing table

Tags: sqlite, self-join

```
media_subscriptions
+----+--------------------------+
| id | target_metadata_item_id  |
+----+--------------------------+
| 30 | 19039                    |
| 31 | NULL                     |
| 32 | NULL                     |
| 33 | NULL                     |
| 34 | NULL                     |
| 35 | NULL                     |
| 36 | NULL                     |
| 37 | 18976                    |
+----+--------------------------+

metadata_items
+-------+-----------------+-----------+
| id    | guid            | parent_id |
+-------+-----------------+-----------+
| 18976 | id://265        | NULL      |
| 18977 | id://265/1      | 18976     |
| 19039 | id://841        | NULL      |
| 19040 | id://841/1      | 19039     |
| 19041 | id://841/1/1    | 19040     |
| 19224 | id://841/1/2    | 19040     |
| 19966 | id://265/1/1    | 18977     |
| 19967 | id://290        | NULL      |
| 19968 | id://376        | NULL      |
+-------+-----------------+-----------+
```

I have the above two tables with data. The `parent_id` column defines how each row in metadata_items relates to any other row, which is also evidential by each row's `guid`. The `parent_id` can be nested by a root ID having a child, and that child having a child (if that makes sense). The `target_metadata_item_id` column from `media_subscriptions` relates to the `id` column of the `metadata_items` table. I want to get a `COUNT(*)` of any records from the `metadata_items` table that have an associated record in `media_subscriptions` based on a search of `guid`. Ultimately, if there is a matching record, the count should only ever be 1, and 0 if not, but I'm using `COUNT(*)` just in case there's ever a duplicate record in the `media_subscriptions` table, and then I'm just checking elsewhere if it returns `> 0`.

Some examples of what I'm trying to accomplish:

- `guid='id://841'` would return 1 because its root parent id (19039) is referenced by `id` 30 in `media_subscriptions`.
- `guid='id://841/1/1'` would return 1 because its root parent id (19039) is referenced by `id` 30 in `media_subscriptions`.
- `guid='id://290'` would return 0 because its root parent id (19967) is NOT referenced by ANY column in `media_subscriptions`.

Here's what I've got right now, which obviously isn't working as I'd intend (take it easy on me, I'm a noob with database administration, and am just starting to learn).

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `metadata_items` AS `t1`
 LEFT JOIN `metadata_items` AS `t2` ON t1.id = t2.parent_id
 INNER JOIN `media_subscriptions` AS `subscriptions` ON t1.id = subscriptions.target_metadata_item_id
 WHERE t1.guid='id://841'
```

This correctly returns 1, but if I switch out the last line with `WHERE t1.guid='id://265/1/1'` it returns 0 where I'd like it to return 1. Obviously I'm doing this very incorrectly, but I'm really not sure how to go about getting where I need to be.

Comment: Is it possible that intermediate (not root) item node is referenced by a subscription?

Comment: No, only a root item node will ever be referenced by a subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
(
SELECT id, guid, parent_id, id _id_, guid _guid_, parent_id _parent_id_
FROM metadata_items
UNION ALL
SELECT cte.id, cte.guid, cte.parent_id, src.id, src.guid, src.parent_id
FROM cte
JOIN metadata_items src ON cte._parent_id_ = src.id
)
SELECT cte.id, cte.guid, cte.parent_id, MAX(target_metadata_item_id) IS NOT NULL 
FROM cte 
LEFT JOIN media_subscriptions src ON cte._id_ = src.target_metadata_item_id
GROUP BY cte.id, cte.guid, cte.parent_id
ORDER BY cte.id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=443816fefe7d68deb09e5a90faefee9d)

If you need the data for one separate record only then add proper WHERE.

Comment: That does does the trick! I only ever need to check one record at a time, so adding the WHERE clause does exactly what I need it to do. :-)